# SlugField in Django and overriding save

Tags: python, django

I am writing an app and learning at the same time. I am about to implement the a SlugField in on of my models, in an example piece of code I found on Tango with Django the author overrode the save function. I am having a hard time understanding why they would do this.

Code from Tango with Django:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to understand why there was a need to override the save function when using the slug field.

Comment: how else would your application know what field to create the slug against ? Example, in this case - the slug is against the `name` field. So, this happens on save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of overiding the save method is to perform some actions each time an instance of the model is saved.

In your example, everytime an instance of your model is saved, the `save` method will transform the name value into a slug value with the function `slugify()` and save it into the slug field.

It's a way to automatically transform the name value into a slug and then saving it in the slug field.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #this line below give to the instance slug field a slug name
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        #this line below save every fields of the model instance
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For instance, in a form for this model, you wont have to include an input for the slug field, the save method will populate it based on the value of the name input.