# Django mptt - how to show full name

Tags: django, django-models, django-mptt

is there any option to show full name in Django mptt?

For example, I have model:

```
class RecipeCategory(MPTTModel):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Nazwa kategorii')
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Pełna nazwa')
body = models.TextField(verbose_name='Opis kategorii', blank=True, help_text='To pole nie jest obowiązkowe. Jeśli chcesz, możesz napisać co konkretnie ma być dodawane do tej kategorii.')
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Tło', default='defaultbgcategory.jpg' ,verbose_name='Tło kategorii', help_text='Dodając zdjęcie jesteś w stanie wyróżnić kategorię, jeśli jednak tego nie zrobisz nic się nie stanie. :)', null=True, blank=True)
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True)
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', related_name='children', db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Kategoria')
subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='subscribed_category', blank=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

Model has title, parent field and full name, how to save full name containing title and parent title like: Title - parent title. In template it's not problem, but I try to create this in rest framework.

Comment: You can overide the save method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176569/slugfield-in-django-and-overriding-save.

Comment: This is it! Thank you. :)